# twincat 2 axis - follow by updating target position

Tags: position, axis, target, twincat

I have an axis that needs to follow a given position that is constantly changing. the problem is that if I use a "MC_MoveAbsolute" FB then I cannot update the target postion. I have to wait for the motion to finish (or stop it) and once it finishes I can give the new target location. The problem with this is that if the cahnge is big, and/or in the opposite direction, the axis could be quite a bit behind. I would need it to update the target position as soon as it differs from the currently assigned one. it also should not have a harsh stop, so something like start, stop, start new is not a solution. the movement should be as smooth as possible and as up to date as possible.

I have 2 possible solutions:

1) i make many small movements that blend with the previous one, so i can change the target position each mm for example and update it quickly

2) i use two distinct FB for the move, and use as mode mc_aborting so i can overwrite the previous move comand.

what solution is the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to change setup such that your input signal is linked to an Encoder Axis in the NC System. You could then use `MC_GearIn` to couple your slave axis to the 'encoder'.

If this is not possible, I belive [`MC_MoveAdditive`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibmc2/458414219.html&id=) is what you're looking for. It lets you change the target position regardless of whether or not the position was reached during the last cycle.